# Word being modified by whose

Tags: syntactic-analysis, whose, attachment-ambiguity

I came across the following sentence:

> Kiran is Kishore's uncle, whose paternal grandfather has only two children.

I am not clear which person *whose* is referring to - Kiran or Kishore  and why?

Comment: Always the most recent one, by default. Which in this case is *uncle*. In order for it to modify *Kishore*, it would have to be "Kishore, whose paternal grandfather" or some such, not "Kishore's uncle, whose...".

Comment: You may find [ell.se] more useful for answering basic English language questions such as this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to Kishore's uncle (last mentioned before the comma), who is precisely Kiran.

In "Kiran is a friend of Kishore's uncle, whose ...", the paternal grandfather would refer to the uncle, without direct relationship with Kiran, or even a stranger.